# Calling a python function

Tags: python, function

I am trying to make a python library that allows me to make custom tkinter widgets that are more aesthetically pleasing than the built-in ones. However, I have run into a problem while defining a few functions.

The problem stems from the difference between functions like append() and str(). While the append function works as follows...

```
somelist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
somelist.append('d')
```

The str() function works like this...

```
somenumber = 99
somenumber_text = str(some_number)
```

You 'call upon' the append function by (1) stating the list that you are modifying (`somelist`), (2) adding a period, and (3) actually naming the append funtion itself (`append()`). Meanwhile you 'call upon' the str function by placing a positional argument (`somenumber`) within its argument area. I have no idea why there is this difference, and more importantly if there is a way to specify which method to use to 'call upon' a function that I define myself?

Thanks...

Comment: The difference is that `append` is a method of `list` objects, while `str` is a function that works on any kind of object at all. (Not the _only_ difference, of course—`append` mutates the list; `str` doesn't mutate any existing values, it creates a new one; `append` returns `None`, `str` returns a useful value; `append` is a builtin function, `str` is actually the constructor call for a builtin class; `append` starts with an `a`, `str` starts with an `s`, etc.— but the one you're asking about.)

Comment: Anyway, if you want to define new functions like `str`, just use a `def` statement at the top level of your module. If you want to define methods like `append` for types you create, use a `def` statement inside the `class` statement that defines the type. If you're not defining any new types, you don't have to worry about methods; just write regular functions.

Comment: OP may have an issue of local scope for the reassignment of `somenumber_text` which doesn't get reflected at the module scope, may just needs `global somenumber_text` in the function. Hard to tell from the actual question posted.

Comment: Yeah I do want to define a method like append because I want to make a function similar to bind, but one that allows me to list all of the events I want to bind at once, and in the definition of my function write out what to do with each event. I was afraid you'd say that I need to make a class because although they are a building block of the language I still cannot seem to grasp the concept.

Comment: are there any urls or examples you know of which defines a function within a class statement like you have suggested?

Comment: All of the basic examples in the [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) chapter of the tutorial include defining methods that way. But you really don't need to do that here.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, function is a group of related statements that perform a specific task.

Functions help break our program into smaller and modular chunks. As our program grows larger and larger, functions make it more organized and manageable.

Furthermore, it avoids repetition and makes code reusable.

**Syntax of Function**

```
def function_name(parameters):
    """docstring"""
    statement(s)
```

Above shown is a function definition which consists of following components.

Keyword def marks the start of function header.
A function name to uniquely identify it. Function naming follows the same rules of writing identifiers in Python.
Parameters (arguments) through which we pass values to a function. They are optional.
A colon (:) to mark the end of function header.
Optional documentation string (docstring) to describe what the function does.
One or more valid python statements that make up the function body. Statements must have same indentation level (usually 4 spaces).
An optional return statement to return a value from the function.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to create a class, or any methods. You can make a plain-old function that's similar to bind, and just take the widget to bind as a normal parameter. For example:

```
def bind_multi(widget, callback, *events):
    for event in events:
        widget.bind(event, callback)
```

That means you have to call this function as `bind_multi(mybutton, callback, event1, event2)` instead of `mybutton.bind_multi(callback, event1, event2)`, but there's nothing wrong with that.